# Accessing the elapsed seconds of a QTimer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, timer

Here is the thing:
I'm having:

```
 QTimer *timer1;
```

That I'm connected to a function called time()

```
connect(timer1, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(time()));
```

I would like to connect another timer, called timer2, to another function as soon as the timer has elapsed for example 5 seconds:

```
QTimer* timer2;
```

I saw the different functions/features of QTimer but I'm not finding the right one which tells me how many seconds elapsed from the timer1, to wait for the 5 seconds and then, call the other function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QTimer does not have any total elapsed time. And please, do not try to count the elapsed time in the timeout function. That will be very inaccurate. Start the `timer2` at the same time as you start the `timer1` and set the interval to 5 seconds.

If you need to get a elapsed time from some starting event, you can use [QElapsedTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qelapsedtimer.html). Note that it is not some advanced version of QTimer, so it doesn't have timeout signal.